# How to use CASE in MySQL using CodeIgniter with joins

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter,

I am able to export the data. I have a column called "status" in the excel sheet. In the `status` column I am getting `1,0,0,1,-1,2`.

Now I have to display the string name in the excel sheet like.

```
-1="Pending"
 0="Cancel"
 1="Create"
 2="Verified"
```

I know I have to use `CASE` but I don't know how to use with Codeignator.

I tried below code.

```
$this->db->select('tbl_customer.*,tbl_customer_shipping.*,product_order.*, CASE 
WHEN product_order.o_order_status =-1    THEN "Pending" 
WHEN product_order.o_order_status =0    THEN "Cancel"
WHEN product_order.o_order_status =1    THEN "Create"
ELSE "Verified"
END CASE');
$this->db->from('tbl_customer');
$this->db->join('tbl_customer_shipping', 'tbl_customer.cust_id=tbl_customer_shipping.cust_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->order_by('product_order.o_date_of_added','DESC');

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

But it's not working

I am getting a syntax error

```
Message: syntax error, unexpected 'CASE' (T_CASE)
```

Would you help me out in this?

Finally, I found My solution. I forgot to add the name of the column at the end of the case and I used a double inverted comma.

```
$this->db->select("tbl_customer.*,tbl_customer_shipping.*,product_order.*,CASE 
    WHEN product_order.o_order_status =-1    THEN 'Pending'
    WHEN product_order.o_order_status =0    THEN 'Cancel'
    WHEN product_order.o_order_status =1    THEN 'Create'
    ELSE 'Verified'
END as o_order_status");
```

Comment: `CASE` clause also needs a `END`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739475/convert-mysql-query-containing-case-statement-to-codeigniter-active-record-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code igniter always escaping my SELECT ... CASE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501418/code-igniter-always-escaping-my-select-case-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland, At the end of else I have to use "END"?

Comment: "At the end of else I have to use "END"?" see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I updated image in the question still showing error.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Please check the duplicate link question. It's different

Comment: @craig, I am getting the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`o_order_status =1 THEN "Create" ELSE` "Verified" FROM `tbl_customer` LEFT JOIN' at line 1

Comment: The sintax for CASE should be: **CASE WHEN expr1 THEN value1 WHEN expr2 THEN value2 ... ELSE defaultValue END**. So try replacing "END CASE" by just "END".

Comment: @D.Smania, Yes, I did but still I am getting above error

Comment: I see you found a solution, but also replace `ELSE "Verified"` by `ELSE 'Verified'` since you are already using double quotes for wrap the query.

Comment: OH! Yes, I forgot to update that. Thanks @D.Smania